# Looping through JSON data not working as expected

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following script which is not behaving the way I am expecting it to behave:

```
success: function( widget_shell ) 
{ 
    if( widget_shell.d[0] ) {
        for ( i = 0; i <= widget_shell.d.length - 1; i++ ) {
           $( ".column_" + widget_shell.d[i].column_id ).append( "<div class='widget_" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id + "'>" );
           $( ".widget_" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id ).append( "<div class='widget_content_" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id + "'>" );
           $( ".widget_" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id ).append( "</div>" );
           $( ".column_" + widget_shell.d[i].column_id ).append( "</div>" );
        }
    }
```

This produces HTML like this:

```
<div id="divMain">
    <div class="column_1 ui-sortable">
        <div class="widget_9">
            <div class="widget_content_9"></div>
            <div class="widget_content_9"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column_2 ui-sortable">
        <div class="widget_9">
            <div class="widget_content_9"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column_3 ui-sortable">
        <div class="widget_58">
            <div class="widget_content_58"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "Widget_Shell",
            "column_id": 1,
            "widget_id": 9
        },
        {
            "__type": "Widget_Shell",
            "column_id": 2,
            "widget_id": 9
        },
        {
            "__type": "Widget_Shell",
            "column_id": 3,
            "widget_id": 58
        }
    ]
}
```

So basically, I should be seeing only 1 widget per column based on the JSON data, which is fine, but for some reason, I am ending up with 2 contents in the first columns widget...

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery function searches the whole document when selecting elements using `$("...")`. In your case, in the second iteration there are two `.widget_9` elements and each one gets a `<div>` appended.

What you want is only appending to the just created element, which can be done with `.appendTo`:

```
var $widget = $("<div class='widget_" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id + "'>")
                .appendTo(".column_" + widget_shell.d[i].column_id);

$("<div class='widget_content_" + widget_shell.d[i].widget_id + "'>")
  .appendTo($widget);
```

`$widget` is overwritten with one new element each iteration, so you're not messing with elements of the previous iteration.

Note that jQuery knows how to create elements with `$("<div>")`, so there is no need for the closing tag. You should also declare `i` as in `var i`.

Comment: Nicely debugged, +1. Probably worth mentioning the `i` thing and not needing or wanting the `append("</div>")`.